# compilation error with iostream usage for console program

Tags: c++, shell, variables, istream

I wanted to make an C++ programm to learn more about terminal input an variables, but I get this error message every time I try to compile it:

```
var.cpp: In Funktion »int main()«:
var.cpp:16:8: Fehler: Anweisung kann die Adresse der überladenen Funktion nicht auflösen
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int z;
    z = 1;
    cout << z << endl;

    int z2 = 7;

    int I;
    cin >> I;

    cin.get;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess it is telling you (indirectly) that `cin.get` is a non-static function. You're supposed to call it. With arguments.

Comment: `cin.get` requires `()`. It's a function call, and must have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am somewhat guessing since I don't understand German(?), but `cin.get` is a function, so you need to add the parenthesis:

```
cin.get();
```

Answer (score 1):

`cin.get` is a function, you have to call it as such, which means parenthesis and an argument of where you want the variable captured to.  Here's an example to look at [istream::get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/)

so the question is what are you trying to do with the get. You might want `cin.get()` but you might be looking to do something else; can't tell from the question.